# Displaying 12-h time in Perl using DateTime

Tags: perl, datetime

This perl script produces a datestamp and timestamp. 
Is there a simple way to display the time in a 12 hour format with AM/PM displayed?

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;

my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'Pacific/Honolulu' );

my $dt = DateTime->now(time_zone =>'Pacific/Honolulu');
my $offset = $tz->offset_for_datetime($dt);

$timestamp = $dt->hms(':');
$datestamp = $dt->mdy('/');

print "$datestamp at $timestamp\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Most date-time modules will provide access to the C function `strftime` or a re-implementation of it. In format specifications provided to `strftime`, you can use the following patterns:

- `%I`: The hour as a decimal number using a 12-hour clock.
- `%l`: The hour as a decimal number using a 12-hour clock. Single digits are preceded by a blank.
- `%p`: Either "AM" or "PM".
- `%P`: Either "am" or "pm".

DateTime objects have a method called `strftime`. For example,

```
$ perl -e'
   use DateTime qw( );
   my $now = DateTime->now( time_zone => "local" );
   CORE::say $now->strftime("%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p %z");
'
2019/06/02 09:45:37 PM -0400
```

As @Nilesh Bhimani tried to point out, the DateTime module is rather heavy, and it's not required for this task (especially if you want to use local time or UTC) because the POSIX module provides `strftime` as well. For example,

```
$ perl -e'
   use POSIX qw( strftime );
   my $now = time;
   CORE::say strftime("%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p %z", localtime($now));
'
2019/06/02 09:45:37 PM -0400
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $datestring = strftime "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y %P", localtime;
printf "date and time - $datestring\n";

my $datestring = strftime "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y %P", gmtime;
printf "date and time - $datestring\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. It's usually a good idea to add a bit of explanation and not just post code.

Comment: This answer would also benefit from providing the correct output --it still uses a 24-hour clock even the question is about how to use a 12-hour clock instead-- and providing it in the same format the OP used.